# Load DataGrid based on an input by using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datagrid

This issue has been nagging at me for days now. Here's the situation:

I have a `DataGrid` that has no data loaded into it. I also have a `Input Text` that uses *AJAX* and *jQuery* to show an existing list of values that a user can choose from as they type. This is a search system that will pull up all the records based on what the user has input. I then have an `Input Button` that needs to populate the `DataGrid` when pressed. What I need *AJAX* for is to refresh that `DataGrid` every time the button is pressed without refreshing the entire page, hence an input instead of an asp. My problem is getting the *JavaScript*/*jQuery* to call the method that will be used. I also need it to get the value of the `InputText` and use that for the search. Here is what I have so far (incomplete; need help completing).

**DataGrid** (This was copied from another `DataGrid` using the same data, just shortened. Probably isn't coded right.)

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="Display" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Line</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LineNumber" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LineNumber") %>'
                        runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Date</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="CreateDate" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CreateDate", "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'
                        runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Operator</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Operator" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Operator") %>'
                        runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery** (This is placed on the `Button`'s "onclick".)

```
function refresh() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/PopulateGrid",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (result) { alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText); }
            }
            );
        };
```

**Code Behind** (I want to try and use the code behind but if a Handler is needed, please let me know.)

```
[WebMethod]
    protected void PopulateGrid()
    {
        using (Entities ent = new Entities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QCConnString"].ToString()))
        {
            string oper = Request.QueryString["getData"].ToString();
            AllDataSources ds = new AllDataSources();
            Display.DataSource = ds.refreshData(ent, oper);
            Display.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I will update this as I get closer to the answer or have come to a solution. I really hope someone can help me solve this issue. I've struggled for so long.

Comment: Can't you just put the button and the grid in an update panel, and populate the grid that way?

Comment: I heard using MS AJAX is not a good idea.. So I'd like to try and avoid that. But I will consider it as a last resort.

Comment: You're going to need an async callback to do the binding, so I don't think you have a lot of options. You can't bind the DataGrid on the client. If MS AJAX is the right tool for the job you should use it.

Comment: Yeah but I'm pretty stubborn when it comes to finding ways to do things. :P I'll probably try a few more things before giving in. XD

Comment: I can understand that, but you shouldn't let stubborness complicate your design. If you don't want to use MS AJAX, I would just use jQuery for everything. Otherwise, you should probably follow the intended path.

Comment: I'm new in the work force and always learning though. On top of that, I don't mind the design right now just because this is a test project. Once I get it working, I clean it up and add it to the main. :)

But thank you~

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in the way you're doing it now. You will have to use asp.net update panels in order to load the asp:datagrid in a ajaxified manner.

Another solution which I use often, is to get rid of the asp:datagrid (if you need a more ajax enabled grid) and use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) which is a ajax enabled grid. This way you **can** use the jquery ajax posts an call your webmethods which must return a xml or json dataset. There are lot of examples out there, for example [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx) is a starting point to understand some of the basics of the grid. Also not forget the [demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) of jqGrid.

Comment: Eh, I honestly don't believe that it can't be done. It may not be able to be done this way but there's gotta be another way. No, I will not use the Update Panels. I hear that using MS AJAX is a big no no... So I'd like to only use it as a last resort if possible.

I would also hate to change from the DataGrid. This is a test project for the main one that uses a DataGrid and I've already enabled a date look-up and paging for that DataGrid. The sad thing is that the page refreshes and I don't want it to.

But I will definitely look into the jqGrid. Thank you so much for the advice. :D

Comment: Maybe it can be done but against what price (time, money, workarounds, hacks, constraints)? I have never seen implementations of what you want and a quick search doesn't give me much hope. The fact is that the asp:datagrid just isn't ment to be a ajax control. Let us know if you find something!

Comment: Yeah, it's nice in that it makes a lot of stuff (paging, searching, updating, editing, etc) a lot easier but when it comes to AJAX, it's basically flips AJAX off and walks away. XD But I will try a few more things, I'm pretty stubborn. The page isn't all that big so having it refresh completely is no biggie if it comes to that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to put the code below in a Generic Handler (.ashx), this would basically generate the HTML you want.  I think this is a pretty hard way to go about what you're trying to do, but it would work.

```
public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            //Instead of making a new DataGrid from scratch, you could also load an in-memory
            //instance of a page with the DataGrid on it.  You'd then have to get the DataGrid from that page.
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

            //Set up your columns based on the form values here.
            //Instead of a DataTable, you could use any IEnumerable data source.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("TestCol");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["TestCol"] = context.Request.Form["myData"].ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dg.DataSource = dt;
            dg.DataBind();

            //Create an in-memory target Page, then add your DataGrid to it.
            System.Web.UI.Page p = new System.Web.UI.Page();
            p.Controls.Add(dg);

            //Create a StringWriter that will contain the HTML.
            //Execute the page, and voila, you got your rendered DataGrid.
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            context.Server.Execute(p, writer, false);

            context.Response.Write(writer.ToString());
            context.Response.End();

        }
```

Comment: Baw, so close. Sadly, the `DataGrid` doesn't want to change. Why DataGrid?! Whhhyyyyy?!